# Does snowflake support geometry data type which is used in sql server?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does snowflake support geometry data type, which is used in SQL server? i only see geography data type in snowflake, whether same data from sql server to snowflake can be stored from geometry data type to geography data type column?

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake supports only GEOGRAPHY data type. It's different than geometry data so you can not store them directly but you can try to convert it on SQL Server:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a17a9320-8360-4497-942a-c3cbcec1d4cf/how-to-convert-geometry-to-geography-?forum=sqlspatial

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake support [GEOMETRY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-geospatial.html#label-data-types-geometry) data type:

> The GEOMETRY data type represents features in a planar (Euclidean, Cartesian) coordinate system.
>
> The coordinates are represented as pairs of real numbers (x, y). Currently, only 2D coordinates are supported.

> The units of the X and Y are determined by the spatial reference system (SRS) associated with the GEOMETRY object. The spatial reference system is identified by the spatial reference system identifier (SRID) number. Unless the SRID is provided when creating the GEOMETRY object or by calling ST_SETSRID, the SRID is 0.